# Xpath with multiple CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath, intern

I am absolutety new to xpath. I am trying to fetch an element which CAN have multiple css. I say can because it depends on the size of the window if the browser is not at max then we hide the the element.

Element when not hidden

```
<td class="foo">..</td>
```

Element when hidden

```
<td class="foo bar">...</td>
```

For example
The structure looks like

```
<table>
  <td>...</td>
  .
  .  
  .
  <td class="foo bar"></td>
<table>
```

No matter whether it is hidden or visible I still want to get the element using class foo. The xpath that I have written looks like

```
.then(pollUntil('return document.evaluate("//td[@class = \'foo\' and position() = 10]//td[contains(@class, \'Clickable\')]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue', 8000))
```

and fails when it is hidden. How do I search for the element based on class foo.
After browsing on internet I tried doing something like this

```
.then(pollUntil('return document.evaluate("//td[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " foo ") and position() = 10]//td[contains(@class, \'Clickable\')]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue', 8000))
```

but then I get the error of `syntaxError: Missing ) after argument list`

Answer (score 0):

> but then I get the error of syntaxError: Missing ) after argument list

You forgot a closing `)`. I prefer to always first write the XPath and run it with an input XML document to be sure it is correct, before applying it to JavaScript or whatever language you want to use it in, for instance with [XPathTester.com](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath).

Your code:

> ```
> .then(pollUntil('return document.evaluate("//td[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " foo ") and position() = 10]//td[contains(@class, \'Clickable\')]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue', 8000))
> ```

contains the following XPath:

```
//td[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' foo ') and position() = 10]//td[contains(@class, 'Clickable')]
```

When tried against your corrected XML/HTML, [you get this (click to see)](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/ac54464097f755fd3a6201f4f75bff92), which shows you have no hits.

So, before we attempt to fix your syntax error, we should try to make the XPath working. The first part:

```
//td[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' foo ') and position() = 10]
```

Correctly selects the tenth TD, but can also be written more simply as (selecting the 10th TD):

```
//td[10][contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' foo ')]
```

If you mean to find the tenth TD that has this class set, then your expression was wrong and you should append `[10]` to the end of it.

Now for the second part:

```
//td[contains(@class, 'Clickable')]
```

Unfortunately, I cannot say much about it, because there is nothing in you source XML that suggests a descendant-or-self element that has the word `Clickable` in the class attribute. So I am just leaving it in to assume it is correct.

Now back to your error. Let's write your JavaScript without the XPath first:

```
.then(
    pollUntil(
    'return document.evaluate(
        \'X\', 
        document, 
        null, 
        XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, 
        null)
    .singleNodeValue'
    , 8000))
```

That looks OK so far, Now let's add the XPath, where we first rigorously replace all single quotes with double quotes:

```
//td[10][contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " foo ")]//td[contains(@class, "Clickable")]
```

Et voilà:

```
.then(
    pollUntil(
    'return document.evaluate(
        \'//td[10][contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " foo ")]//td[contains(@class, "Clickable")]\', 
        document, 
        null, 
        XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, 
        null)
    .singleNodeValue'
    , 8000))
```

The problem with your original code was three-fold:

1. The XPath never returned any results as written (but you were pretty close and perhaps it applies correctly with your real data)
2. The `'Clickable'` part contained single quotes in your code
3. The first argument to `document.evaluate` is a string forming the XPath, and you enclosed it with the same double quotes as the quotes inside the XPath. Fixed by escaping it as single quotes so that it correctly encloses the XPath, which uses double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, you can simply use:

1) if it is supposed to be used in Intern, then: 
`remote.findByCssSelector(".foo")` - find 1 element
`remote.findAllByCssSelector(".foo")` - find all elements

2) with javascript:
`document.querySelector(".foo")` or `document.querySelectorAll(".foo")`